# I need to return a variable from my game

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, methods

As I have the game now, it will loop as many times as the user chooses and I need to take the amount played and divide the amount of wins to get a win percentage. I am not sure how to go about this so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 function rockPaperScissors(){
            function game(wantToPlay){
                if (wantToPlay=="Yes"||wantToPlay=="yes"){
                    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
                    //gets a random number
                    var computerChoice = Math.random();

                    //assigns that random number to be either rock, paper or scissors based on the number
                    if (computerChoice < .34) {
                        computerChoice = "rock";}
                    else if(computerChoice <= .66) {
                        computerChoice = "paper";}
                    else {
                        computerChoice = "scissors";
                    }
                    console.log("computerChoice: " + computerChoice);
                    console.log("userChoice: " + userChoice);

                    //compares the computer choice to the user choice and then prints out the outcome on the page.
                    function compare(choice1,choice2){
                        console.log(choice1 + "<-----User");
                        console.log(choice2 + "<-----Computer");
                        if (choice1==choice2){
                            alert("It was a tie!");
                            game("yes");
                        }
                        if (choice1=="rock"){
                            if (choice2=="scissors"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="You win. Rock crushes scissors.";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                            }
                            if (choice2 =="paper"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Paper smothers rock.";

                            }
                            /**else{
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Rock crushes scissors";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                            }**/
                        }
                        else if (choice1=="paper"){
                            if (choice2=="rock"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="You win. Paper smothers rock.";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                            }
                            if (choice2 =="scissors"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Scissors cut paper.";

                            }
                           /** else{
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Paper smothers rock.";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                            }**/
                        }
                        else if (choice1=="scissors"){
                            if (choice2=="paper"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="You win. Scissors cut paper.";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                            }
                            if (choice2 =="rock"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Rock crushes scissors.";
                            }
                           /** else{
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Scissors cut paper.";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                            }**/
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Very funny. Read the help menu and do it right.");
                            game("yes");
                        }

                    };
                    compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
                }

                //this only runs if the user does not type yes
                else{
                    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="Well alrighty then.";
                    document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                    document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                }
            }
            //promts the start of the game and loops x amount of times based on user input.
            var start = prompt ("Do you want to play?","Yes");
            var i = prompt("How many times do you want to play?", 5);
            for (n = 0; n < i; n ++){
            game(start);
        }}
```

Comment: Protip: store your elements as variables, and stop abusing `innerHTML` D:

Comment: You have to *count* the wins and losses.  Seems as though you could do this easily with a couple of variables you increment within your if statement, then show that divided by the number of games played to get the percentage...

Comment: cale_b would that work inside the if statements, the game is looped so wouldn't the wins and losses variables reset to their assigned values each time the game is looped?

Comment: I guess the easiest way to find out is to try it.

Comment: That does not work, it does not save the value incremented just resets it everytime the game loops

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables, like this (in `<body onload="initVars()">` and create function `initVars()`)

```
var wins=0;
var plays=0;
```

When player wins, you do `wins++` and `plays++`, when loses - only `plays++`.
When game ends you do `wins/plays`.